# Error in Archiving the app after updating xcode to 4.5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, testflight, xcode4.5

before updating the archiving process work good but after updating when i archiving the app it gives a linker error to TestFlight Library error is:-

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/dhirajchoudhary/Documents/MyWorldOfExpo/HRWeekIndia/TestFlightSDK1.0/libTestFlight.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is any one know how to link the testflight library in Xcode 4.5, iOS 6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty much exactly what the error message says: your app supports multiple architectures, including armv7s. You're trying to link with the TestFlightSDK which doesn't include the armv7s architecture.

You need to either:

- Use a newer version of the TestFlight SDK which includes the new armv7s architecture. I'm not sure if this exists yet
- Remove the armv7s architecture from your application. It *should* still work on the iPhone 5 (which is the only device to use armv7s currently) but you would need to test

Comment: yes this error remove after using new version of TestFlight which included the armv7 architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Test Flight SDK 1.1, which with support for arm7